# when I insert data first time, it will show null but second time show inserted..how can i fix it?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

when I insert data the first time, it will show null but the second time show inserted..how can I fix it?

```
const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm();
    const [imgURL, setImgURL] = useState(null);

    const onSubmit = data => {
        const addData = {
            name: data.name,
            price: data.price,
            quantity: data.quantity,
            imgURL: imgURL
        }
        const url = `http://localhost:5000/addProduct`;
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify(addData)
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(result => {
                if (result) {
                    alert('product added successfully');
                }
            })
    };
```

Comment: *What* is showing null?

Comment: #backend :        app.post("/addProduct", (req, res) => {
        const newProduct = req.body;
        productCollection.insertOne(newProduct)
            .then(result => {
                res.send(result.insertedCount > 0)
            })

Comment: {"_id":{"$oid":"60cb67c0a961900f20d9944a"},"name":"Onion","price":"50","quantity":"1","imgURL":null}

Comment: second data: {"_id":{"$oid":"60cb67dba961900f20d9944b"},"name":"Onion","price":"50","quantity":"1","imgURL":"https://i.ibb.co/Jzsnsfc/Onion.png"}

Comment: I see, so this is more a backend issue. What debugging steps have you taken? Are you ***sure*** you are sending the correct data from the frontend? Have you ***verified*** you get the correct data per request in the backend? Try to identify where it breaks down. Can you edit your question to include your backend server code? Code in comments isn't particularly easy to read most of the time.